# Why can't I change the name attribute of this input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an ol with several  li like this:

```
<ol id="monday">
    <li id="zero1"><input type="hidden" name="mo[]" value="cero1"><button type="button"">15</button></li>
</ol>
<button type="button" onclick="update()"> Update</button>
```

And I can change the content of the ol, but when I try to change the name attribute with jquery it remains the same, Is there something wrong with my function?

```
function update(){
    $("#monday input").each(function (){
        $("this").attr("name", "mo[]");
    });
}
```

Comment: `$("this")` is not same as `$(this)`.

Comment: You also appear to be updating the name to the same value as it already has

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a keyword and it should not be a **String** here

```
function update(){
    $("#monday input").each(function (){
        $(this).attr("name", "mo[]");
    });
}
```